# jQuery 2.x - .on function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am developing a website which has got a button and then show the content if clicked and when clicked again, it should hide it. Now my script does this once, so when I click, it shows the content, when I click again, it hides it but when I click again, nothing happens. I googled for it and I found `on(`) function but it is not working. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#togglecont').on('click', function() {
        $('#content').load('content/main.html');
        $('#togglecont').click(function() {
            $('#content').load('content/blank.html');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That looks like Inception...

Comment: Have you tried to understand the code you are using? What happen the third time you click it?

Comment: From the docs [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/): `To remove events bound with .on(), see .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see .one()`

Comment: I tried but I don't know what is wrong with this

Comment: I think this code can be simplified by toggling `.load` argument between `'content/main.html'` and `'content/blank.html'`. Does it make sense?

Comment: @NadirSampaoli if you mean .toggle(), I read that it was removed in earlier versions

Comment: @NadirSampaoli Nadir, sure it makes sense

Comment: @MLL No I don't mean `.toggle()`. Let me see if I can put an answer together.

Comment: @MLL what do you expect what the `.on` and `.click` should do? Both don't remove the callbacks that were already added. So with each click the callback of `.on` is called and an additional callback of `.click` is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#togglecont').on('click', function () {    
         if (!$(this).data('uri') || $(this).data('uri') === "blank") $(this).data('uri', 'main');
         else $(this).data('uri', 'blank');
         $('#content').load('content/' + $(this).data('uri') + '.html');
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable to keep track of the next page to load:

```
$(function() {
    var pages = ['content/main.html', 'content/blank.html'],
        pageToggle = 0;
    $('#togglecont').on('click', function() {
        $('#content').load(pages[pageToggle]);
        pageToggle = (pageToggle + 1) % 2;
    });
});
```

Each time `#togglecont` is clicked `pageToggle` is "toggled" between 0 and 1 thus causing `pages[pageToggle]` to yield one of the two pages cyclically.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVLdw/) shows the behavior, although I had to use `.text()` instead of `.load()` because I don't know how to include external HTML files.